# NG-pattern is not working on angular Editable row

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on Editable row using angualrjs.i wanted to apply  `ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/"` on  below code but it's not working.so ther is any way how to set ng-pattern on it or we can set ng-pattern inside checkName function.

i am trying to implement  Editable row form and using below url

http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-table

```
<span editable-text="user.id" e-name="id" e-form="rowform" onbeforesave="checkName($data, user.id)">
                                    {{ user.id}}
                                </span>

$scope.checkName = function (data, id) {

   if (data === 'null' || data === '') {

    return "Please enter number";
   }

};
```

Comment: Where are you using `ng-pattern`?

Comment: <span editable-text="user.id" e-name="id" e-form="rowform" onbeforesave="checkName($data, user.id)" e-ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/">
                                    {{user.id}}
                                </span>